# What is the Kurtosis of Returns in Geometric Brownian Motion?

Tags: statistics, probability, geometric-brownian

Suppose that $dS_t=S_t(\mu\mathop{dt}+\sigma\mathop{dW_t})$ which has solution
$$S_t=S_0\exp\left(t\left(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)+\sigma W_t\right),$$
such that $W_t$ is a Wiener process, $\mu$ is drift, and $\sigma$ is volatility.
So can
\begin{split}
K(\delta)&=\text{kurt}\left(\frac{S_{t+\delta}-S_t}{S_t}\right),\\
&=\text{kurt}\left(e^{\frac{\delta \sigma^{2}-2\sigma W_t}{2}+\delta\mu+\sigma W_{t+\delta}}-1\right),
\end{split}
be simplified for all $\delta$? In simulations, $K$ bounces around $3$ (for small $\delta$). Note that $W_{t+s}-W_s$ is independent of $s$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you use logarithmic returns instead of relative returns, the kurtosis is exactly 3.

Comment: i.e. $\text{kurt}(\ln(S_{t+\delta}/S_t))=3$, since returns are lognormal?

Comment: Yes. Prices are lognormal, relative returns are (shifted) lognormal, and log returns are of course normal; hence kurtosis equal to 3

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thank you very much :D